# PHP/SQL - Selecting from ALL of a column where another column = 0

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to get this statement to select all of the column called "Roles" where Status = 0. With the code I have it is only picking the first one with status = 0. I feel stupid asking but how could I select all roles where status = 0?
Current Code:

```
    $sql_query="SELECT Role FROM roles Where Status=0";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql_query);
    $input = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $role = array_rand($input, 2);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "You are are a ".$input[$role[1]] . "\n";
```

Note: $dbconfig is coming from a required file in a different location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using array_rand()

> array_rand — Pick one or more random entries out of an array

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Try something like this:

```
    $sql_query="SELECT Role FROM roles Where Status=0";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql_query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $role = $row[0];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "You are are a ".$role . "\n";
   }
```

Based on your comment, maybe this:

```
    $sql_query="SELECT Role FROM roles Where Status=0";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql_query);
    $myRoleArray;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $role = $row[0];
        $myRoleArray[] = $role;
    }
    //You can pick random from $myRoleArray now.
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using "array_rand" from the data given by mySQL it would pick a random "role" from the list and then output just one role rather than all of them.

Comment: But you are not fetching rows. You need an iteration. $input = mysqli_fetch_array($result); returns only one record for you.

Comment: That's the problem I was having, I wanted to save all the data from the column into a array, so then I could use array_rand

Comment: So fetch data in while iteration and add values to an array?

Comment: Yes. Practically so when the user loads the page it would simply pick a random role.